# Erro ao tentar criar um link simbólico Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando executar a criação de um link simbólico no Node.Js porém, estou recebendo erro 'EPERM' ao executar o script.

Script:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let absolute_source = path.resolve('./assets/');
let absolute_target = path.resolve('./public');

fs.symlink(
    absolute_source
    , absolute_target+'/assets'
    , function (err) {
        console.log(err || "Done.");
    }
);
```

Erro:

```
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projetoNode\01_projeto\assets' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projetoNode\01_projeto\public\assets'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'symlink',
  path: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projetoNode\\01_projeto\\assets',
  dest: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projetoNode\\01_projeto\\public\\assets'
}
```

Já olhei as permissões estão ok, olhei também se está como somente leitura e não está.

O que pode ser o causador deste erro e o que posso fazer para resolver?

Obs: Utilizo:

- Windows 10 pro
- Node.Js 6.14.6.

Comment: Cara. pelo que lembro, windows não possui link simbolico. Isso é uma limitação do sistema de arquivos do windows `NTFS`. Mas não uso windows não tenho propriedade para falar.

Comment: Pior que no laravel consigo criar o link simbólico e queria fazer o mesmo pelo node.js para poder evitar ter que criar tudo na pasta pública, porém, não consegui fazer o fs criar...